# Converting from void* to int, in 64 bits Ubuntu, using pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, pipe, void-pointers

my problem is that i need to run a pthread so i can listen a pipe, the thing is i have the pipes in a struc:

```
struct Pipefd {
    int tuberia1[2];
    int tuberia2[2];
};
```

this is the way i create the pthread:

```
intptr_t prueba = pf.tuberia2[0];
pthread_create(NULL,NULL, listenProcess,reinterpret_cast<void*>(prueba));
```

and here is the method i invoke:

```
void *listenProcess(void* x){

    int a = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(x);
    close(0);
    dup(a);

    string word;

    while(getline(cin,word)){

        cout << "Termino y llego: " << word << endl;

    }
}
```

it compile, but i get a segmentation fault, but i dont understand. im newby in c++, i already search alot and didnt found an answer to work, the "reinterpret_cast" is a workaround that i found to compile it without errors.

Thanks for your time, im sorry about my english, it is not my mother language, so any grammar error you point, its well recive.

Comment: How did you instantiate `pf`? On the call stack?? This might be the wrong place, since it go out scope for the thread method!

Comment: pf is initialize before the pthread_create, that part its ok, because i use the first pipe "pf.tuberia1" in another part of my program, but in the same method i call pthread_create().

Comment: Don't do that! There's an `intptr_t` type defined by ANSI C for just this reason. `intptr_t` is a type large enough to store a pointer to an `int`, just because they both have int in the typedef name does not mean you can use them interchangeably. On a 64-bit system depending on which types are 64-bit (pointers definitely, `ints` possibly), you may have to cram this pointer in two `ints`.

Comment: i dont understand what you said, can you give me more info? im really bad with pointer and sizes.

Comment: Put simply, `int` may be 32-bit but `void *` is 64-bit on your system. If you cast a pointer to an `int`, you may lose 32-bits of information. `intptr_t` on the other hand, always has the same size as `void *` (64-bit in your case). In fact, I am pretty sure on your particular platform that `int` is 32-bit. Sometimes you can get away with losing 32-bits of your address, for instance, if all memory is stored in the lower 4 GiB of memory but you do not want to get into this bad habit.

Comment: and how do i convert from intptr_t to int without loosing information?

Comment: You don't, that is the point I am trying to make :) Pointers should not be stored in an `int`. If your structure is supposed to store pointers, then it should either use `intptr_t` or `void *` but not `int`.

Comment: but the dup() method to duplicate file descriptors need an int to function.

Comment: Ah, now I see where your confusion is coming from... file descriptors are not pointers. I'll see if I can write an answer to explain what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks!!! you dont know how i needed this help, you are so kind!! im sorry for taking your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX threads API allows you to pass a generic `void*` for user data when your thread function is first called.

Since you already have the following structure defined:

```
struct Pipefd {
    int tuberia1[2];
    int tuberia2[2];
};
```

Rather than casting a single field of this structure to `void*` you might want to pass a pointer to the actual structure:

```
void* ppf = reinterpret_cast<void *>(&pf);
pthread_create(NULL,NULL, listenProcess,ppf);
```

Now, your modified thread function would look like this:

```
void *listenProcess(void* x){
    Pipefd* ppf = reinterpret_cast<Pipefd *>(x);
    close(0);

    dup(ppf->tuberia2 [0]);

    string word;

    while(getline(cin,word)){
        cout << "Termino y llego: " << word << endl;
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE:

You also had an invalid call to `pthread_create (...)`, you must pass it a pointer to a `pthread_t` variable. This should fix your segmentation fault caused by calling `pthread_create (...)`:

```
void*     ppf = reinterpret_cast<void *>(&pf);
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid,NULL, listenProcess,ppf);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still get  a segmentation fault on pthread_create :(

Comment: @DavidSttivendAngel: Well, I only addressed the issue in your title. You have a far more serious issue that I will correct for you... you cannot pass `NULL` as the thread, because it wants to store the thread ID at that address upon success.

Comment: Thanks Andon, i though i read that you can pass NULL at the Thread id but, i was confuse with the 2 NULL of the arguments, you are so right, thank you for all your help!!!